# How to install Xaw package with header files?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, c, shared-library

I'm having this error on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
checking for X... libraries , headers /usr/include/X11/
configure: error: Cannot find required Xaw header file Box.h; PDCurses cannot be configured
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR**  install missing package by running

```
sudo apt-get install libxaw7-dev
```

There is a pattern on how ubuntu packages are named ... useful feature is ability to search for libraries ... you need Xax with header files ... packages giving headers usually end with `-dev` ... at a terminal search by issuing :

```
apt-cache search Xaw # libraries tend to start with lib and end with dev
```

here I put those restrictions all on same line

```
apt-cache search  Xaw | grep lib | grep -i Xaw | grep dev
```

output

```
libxaw7-dev - X11 Athena Widget library (development headers)
libxaw3dxft8-dev - Extended version of Xaw3d with support for UTF8 (Development files)
```

pick from above listing the closest ... which is

```
libxaw7-dev  # desired package - starts with lib has xaw ends with dev
```

so issue this to install

```
sudo apt-get install libxaw7-dev
```

once installed issue this to list all files contained in package (to see header files)

```
 dpkg -L libxaw7-dev  #  -L flag only works for installed package
```

to show version of installed package issue

```
dpkg -l  libxaw7-dev
```

output

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name              Version      Architecture Description
+++-=================-============-============-===============================================
ii  libxaw7-dev:amd64 2:1.0.13-1   amd64        X11 Athena Widget library (development headers)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there's no answer accepted yet... So let's have a try: On my Ubuntu out-of-the-box machine, first I install necessary development package with headers:

```
sudo apt-get install libxaw7-dev
```

Then I need to tell `./configure` script the correct location to these development files. On my machine this is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. You get this from `apt-cache show libxaw7`. With this knowledge, call

```
./configure --x-libraries=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 1):

***TL;DR:*** Install [libxaw7-dev](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libxaw7-dev) [image: Install libxaw7-dev].

It appears you're building software from source code, and that the software you're building is not Xaw itself, but instead *uses* Xaw by [linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)#Dynamic_linking) against it.

To build software that links to a library, you must install the header files for that library (which is what your error message--"Cannot find required Xaw header file Box.h"--is telling you that you don't have).

In Ubuntu, header files are provided by separate packages, whose names end in `-dev`. In this case, you need [libxaw7-dev](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libxaw7-dev) [image: Install libxaw7-dev]. (You also need [libxaw7](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libxaw7) [image: Install libxaw7], but if you don't already have it, it will be installed automatically when you install the corresponding `-dev` package. In contrast, installing *it* will *not* automatically install its `-dev` package.)

You can install [libxaw7-dev](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libxaw7-dev) [image: Install libxaw7-dev] in the Software Center, or by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libxaw7-dev
```

While you don't have to install `libxaw7` explicitly, you might wish to, so that it's not [automatically removed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Removal_commands) if the `-dev` package is later uninstalled and no other package declares a [dependency](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Package_Dependencies) on it. (Generally speaking, the package manager doesn't know about software you've manually built and installed from source code.) If you wish to do that, replace the second line with:

```
sudo apt-get install libxaw7-dev libxaw7
```

Or just run `sudo apt-get install libxaw` or `sudo apt-mark manual libxaw7`, if you've already installed `libxaw7-dev`.

In the case of this particular library (`libxaw7`), it was easy to guess the name of the package that provides its header files `libxaw7-dev`. Sometimes, it's not so easy. In that case, or in general to find out what official Ubuntu package provides a file (whose filename you know), you can search the [Ubuntu Packages Database](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), under "Search the contents of packages."

[This reveals](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=Box.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) that a number of packages provide files with that or a similar name. However, only one of the search results provides a header file for Xaw: [`libxaw7-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libxaw7-dev) (The file is `/usr/include/X11/Xaw/Box.h`.)

[That search shows](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=Box.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) other related header files provided by two other related packages, which I believe you don't need, since your error message said "Cannot find required *Xaw* header" (and not [*Xaw3d*](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xaw3dg-dev) or [*Xaw3dxft*](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xpaint-dev)). However, in case you need those related libraries' `Box.h` files, they are provided by the [xaw3dg-dev](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xaw3dg-dev) [image: Install xaw3dg-dev] and [xpaint-dev](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xpaint-dev) [image: Install xpaint-dev] packages.

Comment: Still doesn't help - https://travis-ci.org/techtonik/PDCurses/builds/99428113